# Grafana - How to upgrade

Tags: grafana

I use grafana 2.1 and created multiple dashboards, templates etc.

I would like to upgrade to grafana 2.6. Is there any way to upgrade to 2.6 without affecting the existing dashboards?

Answer (score 0):

There are no [breaking changes](http://grafana.org/download/) between 2.1 and 2.6. In theory upgrading should be a simple matter of installing the new packages. I personally have upgraded from 2.1.3 to 2.5 to 2.6 with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

For windows version, I just had to copy the data/grafana.db and the data/plugins directory from the old installation to the new installation directory. Just make sure the newer version does not have any breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Grafana to higher versions for better features and also import your previous dashboard to the new version without any problem by using Import/Export feature.